# Xarray get matching variable names between two datasets

Tags: python-xarray

I have two similar Netcdf files with the same structure, e.g :

```
file1 = xr.open_dataset("file1.nc")
file2 = xr.open_dataset("file2.nc")

print(file1)
```

```
Dimensions:       (Number_of_points: 232678)
Dimensions without coordinates: Number_of_points
Data variables:
    XLON          (Number_of_points) float64 ...
    XLAT          (Number_of_points) float64 ...
    VERSION       int32 ...
    BUG           int32 ...
    STORAGETYPE   |S40 ...
    SPLIT_PATCH   |S1 ...
    SEA           |S40 ...
    WATER         |S40 ...
    NATURE        |S40 ...
...
```

```
print(file2)
```

```
Dimensions:       (Number_of_points: 232678)
Dimensions without coordinates: Number_of_points
Data variables:
    XLON          (Number_of_points) float64 ...
    XLAT          (Number_of_points) float64 ...
    VERSION       int32 ...
    BUG           int32 ...
    STORAGETYPE   |S40 ...
    SPLIT_PATCH   |S1 ...
    NATURE        |S40 ...
...
```

In one of the files, I have some variables missing (here for example the variables SEA and WATER above)
I want to compare the two files to get the matching variables names between the two datasets, and then iterate over file1 to load only the missing dimensions.
The final result I want is to automatically load :

```
Var1 = file1.SEA
Var2 = file1.WATER
```

Is there an easy way to do this with Xarray ?

Thank you,

Théo

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the question. Is getting the list of variables with `file1.data_vars` and then comparing with `file2`'s in a line of normal python what you need?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know whether or not a variable in file 1 exists in file 2, and then read only the list of matching variables from file1

Comment: Like this: `file1[[x for x in file1.data_vars if x in file2.data_vars]]` ?

Comment: I tried this it worked perfectly ! Thanks !

Comment: OK I added as an answer

Answer (score 0):

(Copying from my comment, which seems to have been successful)

You can fall back to regular python here:

```
file1[[x for x in file1.data_vars if x in file2.data_vars]]
```